# How to remove indexeddb and firebaseLocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear indexeddb on my website. How can i resolve it.

```js
function deleteAllData() {
  window.alert('Delete Sucessful');
  const dbs = await window.indexedDB.databases();
  dbs.forEach(db => { window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db.name) });
  console.log(dbs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexedDB.databases()` is a promise, you have to wait for its completion before proceeding.

Similarly, `db.deleteDatabase()` returns an `IDBOpenDBRequest` object immediately, and performs the deletion operation asynchronously. You should wait for the success callback of the request to check that the DB deletion has completed, something like

```js
async function deleteAllData() {
  const dbs = await indexedDB.databases()
  await Promise.all(
    dbs.map(db => new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        const request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db.name)
        request.onsuccess = resolve
        request.onerror = reject
      }
    ))
  )
  window.alert('Delete Sucessful');
}
```